# Api Platform use Post to get data using an input

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, api-platform.com

I'm working with Api Platform, Symfony and Doctrine. I'm expecting a JSON of an object from my frontend, which is essential in procuring the data from my backend. Since `GET` requests don't/should not have a body, I believe a `Post()` Operation is the best way to achieve my goal. I have added an attribute to my entity, which resembles the following:

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: EntityRepository::class)]
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new Post(
            input: InputDto::class,
            provider: StateProvider::class,
            output: OutputDto::class,
            uriTemplate: 'entity/{variable}',
            uriVariables: ['variable' => 'variable'],
        )
    ]
)]
```

My state provider resembles the following example:

```
class StateProvider implements ProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        private RequestStack $requestStack
    )
    {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    }

    public function provide(Operation $operation, array $uriVariables = [], array $context = []): object|array|null
    {
        $variable = $uriVariables['variable'] ?? null;
        
    // logic
        
        $outputDto = new OutputDto($dataProcuredFromLogic);

        return $outputDto;
    }
}
```

The logic seems to work just fine. If I add `print_r($outputDto);` just before the return statement, I get exactly the data I expected. But when executing the request, the response is just the exact same `InputDto` which I have sent through the body of the request, not the returned `$outputDto` of the provider.
This makes me wonder if what I've hoped to achieve is even possible.

I have tried to use a state processor instead of a provider and using the exact same logic. The only differences being that I did not need a `RequestStack` to get the input data, with it being in the parameters of the `process()` Method and me having to change the return type of the `process()` Method to my `OutputDto`. What I have gotten there was an error that looked like this:

```
"[Semantical Error] line 0, col 75 near 'property = :property_p1': Error: Class App\\Entity\\Entity has no field or association named property"
```

I am guessing in has something to do with Doctrine, because of `":property_p1"` resembling what would seem like a parameter that was set on a `QueryBuilder`, but as I said, the logic, including my DQL Queries, seemed to work just fine when I printed my results using `print_r()`.

I'm not sure if I should use a controller as I have read that they are discouraged in the Api Platform documentation.

Could you help me return the actual wanted output?

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!